# Why am I losing formatting while using simple_format in ruby on rails 4.2.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redactor

When I use html_safe,

```
<%= @micropost.content.html_safe  %>
```

I get the following output with proper formatting.

[image]

But when I use simple_format, I lose the center align and getting line breaks in list which I do not want.

```
<%= simple_format(auto_link(@micropost.content, html: { target: '_blank' }), {}, :sanitize => false) %>
```

[image]

This is what I get when I use auto_link alone with sanitize false.

```
<%= auto_link(@micropost.content, html: { target: '_blank' }, sanitize: false) %>
```

[image]

This is what I get when I use auto_link alone with sanitize true.

```
<%= auto_link(@micropost.content, html: { target: '_blank' }, sanitize: true) %>
```

[image]

This is what I have in the post

```
>> micp.content
=> "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">Pictre </p><h2 style=\"text-align: center;\">restse</h2><h2>sfsdfsdf</h2><p>sdfdsf</p><p style=\"text-align: center;\">dsfds</p><p>sfsdfsdf</p><ol><li>sdfdsfsdf</li><li>sdfsdfdsf</li><li>sdfdsf</li></ol><div>dfsdfsdfsd</div><p style=\"text-align: center;\">dfsdf</p><ol><li>dsfsdf</li><li>sdf</li><li>sdfsd</li></ol><p style=\"text-align: center;\"><br></p>"
>>
```

How do I resolve this and have the formatting which the user wanted in his/her post? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the api documentation:

> `simple_format` - Returns text transformed into HTML using simple
>   formatting rules. Two or more consecutive newlines(\n\n) are
>   considered as a paragraph and wrapped in `<p>` tags. One newline (\n) is
>   considered as a linebreak and a `<br />` tag is appended. This method
>   does not remove the newlines from the text.

So instead of:

```
<%= simple_format(auto_link(@micropost.content, html: { target: '_blank' }), {}, :sanitize => false) %>
```

You should probably do the following:

```
<%= auto_link(@micropost.content, html: { target: '_blank' }, sanitize: false) %>
```

Refer to [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) and [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) for more info.

Comment: I tried your solution and I get only html tags. I have updated the ouput in the question.

Comment: Try with `sanitize: true`

Comment: I am getting the output now but still i am losing the formatting.